# Como puedo saber cuantas veces he usado una funcion en C++

Tags: c++, funciones, dev-c++

```
menu_figuras_geometricas_dosD();
menu_figuras_geometricas_tresD();

//quiero saber cuantas veces accedí hacer el calculo del triangulo
//usted calculo #1 vez el triangulo y se accedo otra vez me presente #2 veces y en las
// otras funciones como el cuadrado si no accedo me presente #0 veces, todo esto me presente
// en una nueva función llama presenta();

triangulo_rectangulo()
cuadrado();
```

Comment: ¿Quieres saber esta información tras la ejecución de la aplicación? En ese caso lo más recomendable es usar un muestreador (*profiler*) como [`gprof`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gprof). Ten en cuenta que esta operación requiere que el ejecutable haya sido preparado para ello. En `gcc` se usa el parámetro `-pg` para ello.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicamente create dos variables globales llamadas:

contTriangulo = 0;
contCuadrado = 0;

Y al final de cada función aumentes ese contador.

Es decir al final de la función del triangulo, antes de retornar el valor, inserta unicamente: contTriangulo++

Y lo mismo para contCuadrado.

Luego en tu función que vaya a visualizar el número de pasadas de cada uno, pasale como parámetros dos números enteros, el del cuadrado y el del triangulo.

Y unicamente visualiza en la frase, esos dos parámetros.

Sería algo así:

```
tipo presenta([int cuadrado,[int triangulo])
{
    /*
        * Visualizas concatenando los números.
        * Creas una variable total o algo así, donde concatenes los dos strings (las 
          dos frases)
        total = "Frase triangulo " + "\n" + "frase cuadrado";
    */

    return total;
}
```

Y finalmente cuando requieras llamar a la función que muestre el total de las frases, llamas a presente(contCuadrado,contTriangulo);

Y con eso ya lo tendrías.

Comment: gracias me ayudo mucho su respuesta muy concreta

Answer (score 2):

Declara una variable estática global (fuera de las funciones). Estas variables globales las puedes utilizar en cualquier lugar del programa, incluidas las funciones. Lo único que tendrás que hacer es incrementar dicha variable dentro de cada llamada a la función a modo de contador.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static uint32_t contador_cuadrado = 0;

void cuadrado ( void )
{
    contador_cuadrado++;
}

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        cuadrado();
        cout<<contador_cuadrado<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

En este ejemplo puedes ver cómo se incrementa `contador_cuadrado` a pesar de trabajar con la variable dentro de la función.
[Aquí](https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/statics.php) tienes más información y ejemplos sobre variables estáticas.
Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: gracias me ayudo de mucho su respuesta